# deleting an element in nested array using filter() function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been trying to delete an element with an ID in nested array.

I am not sure how to use `filter()` with nested arrays.

I want to delete the `{id: 111,name: "A"}` object only.

Here is my code:

```
var array = [{
    id: 1,
    list: [{
        id: 123,
        name: "Dartanan"
    }, {
        id: 456,
        name: "Athos"
    }, {
        id: 789,
        name: "Porthos"
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    list: [{
        id: 111,
        name: "A"
    }, {
        id: 222,
        name: "B"
    }]
}]

var temp = array
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].list.length; j++) {
        temp = temp.filter(function(item) {
            return item.list[j].id !== 123
        })
    }
}
array = temp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `forEach` and execute the function `filter` for every array `list`.

```js
var array = [{    id: 1,    list: [{      id: 123,      name: "Dartanan"    }, {      id: 456,      name: "Athos"    }, {      id: 789,      name: "Porthos"    }]  },  {    id: 2,    list: [{      id: 111,      name: "A"    }, {      id: 222,      name: "B"    }]  }];

array.forEach(o => (o.list = o.list.filter(l => l.id != 111)));
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

To remain the data immutable, use the function `map`:

```js
var array = [{    id: 1,    list: [{      id: 123,      name: "Dartanan"    }, {      id: 456,      name: "Athos"    }, {      id: 789,      name: "Porthos"    }]  },  {    id: 2,    list: [{      id: 111,      name: "A"    }, {      id: 222,      name: "B"    }]  }],
    result = array.map(o => ({...o, list: o.list.filter(l => l.id != 111)}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In the real life i will have dozens of list id's, that is why i was looking to make loops. should i use splice instead? not big fun of splice. Thanks

Comment: There's no need for the second spread, simply `{...o, list: o.list.filter etc`

Comment: @georg yes, you're right but I've updated the answer `:)`

Comment: @Ele: I'm not sure it's better now, because they've tagged with "vue.js" so their data should probably remain immutable.

Comment: @georg got it, however the OP stated this *I want to delete the {id: 111,name: "A"} object only.* cause that I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new array which contains elements with filtered `list` property.

```
const result = array.map(element => (
  {
    ...element,
    list: element.list.filter(l => l.id !== 111)
  }
));
```

You can use Object.assign if the runtime you are running this code on does not support spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) acts on elements:

```js
var myArray = [{something: 1, list: [1,2,3]}, {something: 2, list: [3,4,5]}]

var filtered = myArray.filter(function(element) {
     return element.something === 1;
     // true = keep element, false = discard it
})

console.log(filtered); // logs [{something: 1, list: [1,2,3]}]
```

You can use it like this:

```js
var array = [{
    id: 1,
    list: [{
        id: 123,
        name: "Dartanan"
    }, {
        id: 456,
        name: "Athos"
    }, {
        id: 789,
        name: "Porthos"
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    list: [{
        id: 111,
        name: "A"
    }, {
        id: 222,
        name: "B"
    }]
}]

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  var element = array[i]
  
  // Filter the list
  element.list = element.list.filter(function(listItem) {
      return listItem.id !== 111 && listItem.name !== 'A';
  })
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: very elegant! thank you!!! for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  var element = array[i]
  
  // Filter the list
  element.list = element.list.filter(function(listItem) {
      return listItem.id !== 111 && listItem.name !== 'A';
  })
}